# Using ui:repeat into an p:accordionPanel with parameter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I try to get the selectOneRadio from PrimeFaces work as a single choice question catalog. I tried it like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{exerciseBean.getExerciseListInGrade(5, category.categoryName)}" var="exercises">
    <div>#{exercises.getText()}</div>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{exerciseBean.data}">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{exercises.getChoicesAsString()}"/>  
    </p:selectOneRadio>  
</ui:repeat>
```

I now can display the choices as p:selectOneRadio but now I have to get the selected and show immediately a message (right or wrong).

Exercise:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)    
private Long id;
private String text;
@OneToMany
private List<Choice> choices;
@ManyToOne
private Choice thatsit;
private Long grade;
```

There you can see that i have a List of Choices and also one extra object containing the right one (the right one is also in the List of choices!).

How is it possible to get the selected on in an Method inside my exerciseBean after the user clicked on one of the radioButtons. Note: with ui:repeat I go throw whole exercises it's because there are more then only one.

As you can see in the code above I made an `String data;` in my `ExerciseBean` but if I have more then one how should i know from which question the data came from.

-Domi

Comment: change `<f:selectItems value="#{exercises.getChoicesAsString()}"/>` in to `<f:selectItem value="#{exercises.getChoicesAsString()}"/>`.. For Radio one button we should use only `<f:selectItem />` not `<f:selectItems />`...

Comment: Okay but what should i do next? I still want to Display More than One question row with X selection options!

Comment: You can find out the value of radioButton by each instance of exercise  please provide some more codes to be helpful